# Conda Runtime error when installing PyTorch using anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

When installing pytorch using anaconda I am continiously getting Conda Runtime Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/codehead/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/exceptions.py", line 479, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/codehead/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main.py", line 145, in _main
    exit_code = args.func(args, p)
  File "/home/codehead/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/main_install.py", line 80, in execute
    install(args, parser, 'install')
  File "/home/codehead/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/conda/cli/install.py", line 420, in install
    raise CondaRuntimeError('RuntimeError: %s' % e)
CondaRuntimeError: Runtime error: RuntimeError: Runtime error: Could not open u'/home/codehead/anaconda2/pkgs/pytorch-0.1.11-py27_5.tar.bz2.part' for writing (HTTPSConnectionPool(host='binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.).
```

The command I am using to install PyTorch is

```
 conda install -c soumith pytorch=0.1.11
```

Answer (score 0):

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='binstar-cio-packages-prod.s3.amazonaws.com', port=443): Read timed out.
```

This is an HTTP timeout, most likely due to a flakey internet connection.  From the stack trace, I'm guessing you're running conda 4.2.  Conda 4.3 has longer timeouts, and they're also now configurable.

```
conda update conda
```

Comment: I used conda update conda command and the result is 
All requested packages already installed 
packages in environment at /home/codehead/anacaonda2:

conda 4.2.13 py27_0 conda-forge